# Reflection over the Factory Method Design Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

All examples I find of the Factory Method Pattern are also examples of Abstract Factory Pattern.

See this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    IFactory factory = new ConcreteFactory();
    IProduct product = factory.CreateProduct(); // <== factory method pattern??
    ProcessProduct(product);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Could I say that this line of code:**

```
IProduct product = factory.CreateProduct();
```

**Completely reflects the "spirit" of the Factory Method Pattern?.**

Here, the factory is creating the Product object without the code having knowledge of the specific object's type.

If that's the case then no wonder why they overlap since the author needed a way of building a working example.

I'm making a Dictionary of definitions for the company I work for.

Comment: [.NET Design Patterns](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) this has both .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but the example you provided is not an Abstract Factory Pattern.

Comment: You haven't showed the definition of `CreateProduct`, so we can't tell if it's an abstract or a concrete factory.

Comment: It should be a factory method example, but now I guess that the line "IFactory factory = new ..." reflects the spirit of the Abstract Factory, and the line "IProduct product = factory..." reflects the Factory Method party. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding a factory method can also be part of an implementation of a class, not only of a factory. This often makes sense, when you want to hide a constructor and use a method instead:

```
class Foo{
private Foo(){
   //do something   
}

public static Foo createFoo(){
    //do something
    return new Foo();
}
}
```

Comment: Oh, I just realised that you asked for C#, while my answer was written in Java. I don't know C#, but I guess the concept might still make sense there.

Comment: This almost compiled under .net. You are missing a closing `}` for the class. Also class declarations do not have a `()`: `class Foo{ ... }`. Also in this case `createFoo` would have to be static - otherwise one would need an instance in order to access the method but can't instantiate one because of the private ctor.

Comment: All of your comments were of course right, I fixed the post. Should be more careful when posting pseudo-pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

While the example you provide is technically a factory method, it isn't very useful.  Design patterns are only beneficial insofar as they can simplify development of the target application/feature.

Generally, the benefit of a factory method implementation comes from:

1. Standardizing the creation logic for objects
2. Providing a semantically meaningful interface for object construction

It's unclear how an instance method that takes no parameters would possibly add benefit over a default constructor.

Take a look at the [C# example from the Wikipedia Factory Method article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C.23).  (copied + pasted below)

```
public class Complex
{
    public double real;
    public double imaginary;

    public static Complex FromCartesianFactory(double real, double imaginary)
    {
        return new Complex(real, imaginary);
    }

    public static Complex FromPolarFactory(double modulus, double angle)
    {
        return new Complex(modulus * Math.Cos(angle), modulus * Math.Sin(angle));
    }

    private Complex(double real, double imaginary)
    {
        this.real = real;
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }
}

Complex product = Complex.FromPolarFactory(1, Math.PI);
```

It is useful, because it specifies two factory methods, each with clearly defined parameters and a clearly defined interpretation of how those parameters would be used to construct a valid instance of a well-defined object.  In addition, the constructor is `private` and the factory method is `static`, which ensures that the only means of constructing an instance of that object is to use the factory method.  While it doesn't apply to this example particularly (because all possible `double` parameter values are valid), it would make sense to put validation logic in the factory method or constructor as well.

In general, **the purpose of a factory method is to reduce code complexity by encapsulating object construction** and it is unclear how the example you provided would accomplish that objective.

Comment: The purpose of the factory is not only to reduce code complexity. A most important benefit is that you abstract creation of objects so that in future the internal implementation could change without breaking client's contract. For example, a factory could implement a life time policy management so that created objects live longer and instances are reused.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, +1, I think your comment is helpful... but would you not agree that your example is a particular case of the factory pattern reducing code complexity?

Comment: Yes, in a sense. I didn't mean you are wrong, only that some other light could be casted onto the issue.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, as always :-)